# Ubuntu set fractional scaling to 110%

Tags: gnome, display, 20.04, scaling

Is there any way to set factional scaling in ubuntu 20.04 to 110% instead of 125% or 150%? Because 100% is too small and 125% is too large for me.

Thanks.